# Identify from which domain a web user connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This isn't a technical question yet, since I'm still learning these technologies.

In the footer of their front pages, CompanyA.com and CompanyB.com would include a `<script src="myservice.com/script.js">` referencing my code. For their customers, that script will generate a tiny UI and also connect to **my** nodeJs server.

Since Company A & B pay for my service, I need a way to ensure that company C can't simply copy&paste the same script. Also, I need to be able to identify from which company the connecting user came from.

Is this possible without any server side scripts in company A and B?

Comment: Validate that value of `location.host` is whitelisted on your server

Comment: I'd say "kind of", as normal browsers will send the domain they are on (see e.g. [referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)). However, should an end-user decide to want to copy your script, i don't think you can stop that.

Comment: It's OK as long as it isn't easy copy&paste. Security by obscurity is kind of fine :)